# Error “column '_data' does not exist” ionic 4

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to open a selected file, and resolve a native path from the uri file data. I'm using `FilePath` from `ionic 4`, but when the method "`resolveNativePath`" is executed i'm receiving this error

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): column '_data' does not exist. Available
>   columns: []

**here is my code**

```
selectFile() {
    this.fileChooser.open().then((fileuri) => {
      this.filePath.resolveNativePath(fileuri).then((nativepath) => {
        const filename = nativepath.substring(nativepath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        const folder = nativepath.substring(0, nativepath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        this.file.readAsDataURL(folder, filename).then((str) => {
          const arr = str.split(';');
          const arr1 = arr[0].split(';');
          const mimetype = arr1[1];
          this.OpenFile(nativepath, mimetype);
        });
      });
    });
  }

  OpenFile(filepath, mimetype) {
    this.fileOpener.open(filepath, mimetype).then(() => {

    }, (err) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    });
  }
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve from above code?

Comment: I'm trying to open a file, but to do this I need to convert the file uri to relative path

Comment: Hi  I have the same issue , did you find a solution?